# Formatting Measure based on filter

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I'm looking to format Measure based on filter selection, Based on filter value should be formatted .. if Measure value is more than 100000 then show number in thousands(ex: 100k) else show just number(99,999).

The reason for this for smaller values are showing as 0k instead of value.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [FORMAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/format-function-dax) DAX function to change the way how your data is visualized. If your measure is let say named `Measure` and calculates a sum, for example:

```
Measure = SUM('Table'[Amount])
```

Then change it to save the result in a variable, inspect the value and format it accordingly:

```
Measure 2 = 

VAR
    CalculatedValue = SUM('Table'[Amount])

RETURN
    IF (CalculatedValue < 100000;
        FORMAT(CalculatedValue; "#,##0");
        FORMAT(CalculatedValue; "#,##0,K"))
```

`#,##0` will format the number with thousands separator (the comma) and no decimals, while `#,##0,K` will format it with thousands separator, no decimals, divided by 1000 and with `K` suffix, so the result is as follows:

[image]

Note that depending on your regional settings, you may have to use `,` instead of `;` for parameters separator in the DAX code above.

Comment: Thanks for reply, Im facing issue with formula, Error is " Format is not function". I'm using September 2019 version.

Comment: Here is the Dax Code:                                                                                
  Measure 3 = 
VAR CalculatedValue = sum(EMP_Summary[MemberShip_Volume])
RETURN
    IF (CalculatedValue < 100000,
        FORMAT(CalculatedValue, "#,##0"),
        FORMAT(CalculatedValue, "#,##0,K"))

Comment: This looks like a correct code. It works when I try it. Are you sure you are making a DAX measure and not Power Query custom column for example?

Comment: Yes, Im making Dax Measure, not sure why it is not working. Is there any i can upload pic here?

Comment: Update your question providing all the details, with screenshots if you want.